# Logstash can not connect to Elastic search because wrong ip adress

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

i have this same problem:

[Logstash can not connect to Elastic search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45188125/logstash-can-not-connect-to-elastic-search)

My /conf.d/logstash.conf:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
    ssl => true
    ssl_certificate => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-beats.crt"
    ssl_key => "/etc/pki/tls/private/logstash-beats.key"
    }
}
filter {
    geoip {
    source => "clientip"
    }
}
output {
   elasticsearch {
   host => "http://anotherip, that is not localhost:9200"
   manage_template => false
   index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
}}
```

Error:

error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://localhost:9200/]

Where logstash pick this ip adress? "localhost:9200"

Answer (score 1):

I solve my problem, i just kill the service with kill -9, after this systemctl start service and works well. Thanks.